# How can I handle isDirty in a component?

Tags: angularjs, components, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-components

I'm using Angular 1.5 and am creating a custom drop-down. There are no elements that use ngModel involved. I want to be able to have a form know if my component is dirty, pristine, etc. My thinking is that I'd use ngModel, like I would a directive. However, since there is no linking function in a component, I'm not sure how to do this. Is it even possible?

Let's just say my component template is this:

`<div>{{model.Value}}</div>`

My code is this:

```
angular.component('myThing',  {
    bindings: {
        model: '='
    },
    require: '^ngModel'
})
.controller('myThingController', () => {
    // stuff and things
});
```

I made a really simple example instead of all of my code because I'm not sure where to even begin with using ngModel within a component. I didn't think it served anyone to have me code dump. If more code is required, please feel free to ask and I'll happily expand my example.

I created a simple pen to try to work through this: http://codepen.io/yatrix/pen/rWEJYV?editors=1011

Comment: You can use `require: { ngModel: '^ngModel' }` on your component declaration.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro and where do I access ngModel's goodies? Do I have to inject it into my controller since there is no link function?

Comment: You can access through the controller context, i.e., `this.ngModel` within your controller.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro mind taking a look at my pen? http://codepen.io/yatrix/pen/rWEJYV?editors=1011 I'm not seeing what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `require: { ngModel: '^ngModel' }` on your component declaration. And you can access through the controller context, i.e., `this.ngModel` within your controller.

The following snippet implements an example based on your [codepen](http://codepen.io/yatrix/pen/rWEJYV?editors=1011).

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
  $scope.model = {
    value: "Hello"
  };
});

app.component('myThing', {
  require: {
    ngModel: '^ngModel'
  },
  template: '<div>{{$ctrl.ngModel.value}}</div><br/><button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">Click This</button>',
  bindings: {
    ngModel: '='
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.doSomething = function() {
      console.log(this.ngModel);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <my-thing ng-model="model"></my-thing>

</div>
```

Comment: I was expecting to gain access to NgModelController with ngModel. Maybe I have asked the wrong question...I do appreciate all your help, though.

Comment: @Yatrix ops, you were supposed to get `ngModelController`, sorry about that. On your codepen you've used the `require` in the unnamed way (i.e., `require: '^ngModel'`, so that you'd have to use `this.controllers[0]` instead. Anyways, I've updated my answer, now you have the right `ngModelController` on the snippet, like : `require: { ngModel: '^ngModel' }.

Comment: Ah, okay. I've never seen the syntax you used, so I didn't realize that. Thank you!

Comment: @Yatrix I think it's available for components only, anyways, anything more? If related to this issue, live a comment and I'll be here to help, cheers :{D

Comment: One small thing - I noticed the "Hello" text isn't appearing. Does that need to be displayed differently via ngModel?

Comment: @Yatrix that's because the model value doesn't come from that source anymore, now it's on `this.ngModel.$modelValue` which you cannot access directly from your template.